# syntax of ST monad declaration

Tags: haskell, st-monad

I recently began looking at core libraries on Hackage, and there's a recurring idiom I don't understand. Here's an example from the [ST module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.ST.html):

```
instance Monad (ST s) where
    {-# INLINE (>>=)  #-}
    (>>) = (*>)
    (ST m) >>= k
      = ST (\ s ->
        case (m s) of { (# new_s, r #) ->
        case (k r) of { ST k2 ->
        (k2 new_s) }})
```

In particular, I don't understand `(# new_s, r #)`. I assume the second hash refers to an unboxed value, but the rest is a mystery to me (something to do with "new state", presumably).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(# x, y, z #)` is an unboxed tuple with three elements. See "8.2.2. Unboxed Tuples" at https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/primitives.html.

The rest is basically just an implementation of State.

Comment: In general, `#` in Haskell means it is doing some sort of low level and/or primitive stuff. You must enable the `MagicHash` language extension to even use `#` in names.